# Cannot connect to college Wi-Fi 802.1g

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu.On just installed ubuntu 14.04 I am unable to connect to my college wifi 802.1g.It (khn-wifi)is displayed there in Network Manager menu but when clicked it again and again asks for password. In windows I used my registration number and date of birth as password in seraph authentication for wifi access. But in ubuntu when I filled this info in edit connection dialog box of khn-wifi, it asks for password again and again. And I do not have any CA certificate . Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's "seraph authentication"? Is it some proprietary Wifi authentication protocol? It would also help if you ran [the general Wifi issue diagnosis](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to the results.

Comment: Yes. In windows, I have to give username and password when prompted after clicking khn wifi. Then on opening chrome, seraph authentication website automatically opens in which I have to type my username n password again for starting the net. But how to do this in Ubuntu ? Above diagnosis not working.

Comment: Please describe how the diagnosis method isn't working. Where are you stuck? What is the error message? Be aware that a diagnosis is *not* supposed to solve the problem, only to help reveal its cause (to an experienced reader).

Comment: This is a problem in 14.04 that has been driving me nuts, and it's a problem with the wifi. Ubuntu will never connect to the network. All of my other devices work fine. What will happen is I will type in the password, the authentication window will go away, and the Wifi icon will pulsate for a while. Then about a minute later, a window will pop up asking for authentication to join the same wifi network. If you type in the password again it will do the same thing, and even if you hit [Cancel], the window will still pop back up in another minute.

Comment: @kalipsomatters: Please go to the highest rated answer of http://askubuntu.com/q/425155 and follow the instructions there.  (Pretty please?) ;-)